# Getting rid of all words that contain a special character in a textfile

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I'm trying to filter out all the words that contain any character other than a letter from a text file. I've looked around stackoverflow, and other websites, but all the answers I found were very specific to a different scenario and I wasn't able to replicate them for my purposes; I've only recently started learning about Unix tools.

Here's an example of what I want to do:

Input:

```
@derik I was there and it was awesome! !! http://url.picture.whatever #hash_tag
```

Output:

```
I was there and it was awesome!
```

So words with punctuation can stay in the file (in fact I need them to stay) but any substring with special characters (including those of punctuation) needs to be trimmed away. This can probably be done with sed, but I just can't figure out the regex. Help.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a list of `punctuation` characters that are not to be removed?

Comment: What do you mean by *special characters*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements aren't clear at all but this MAY be what you want:

```
$ awk '{rec=sep=""; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^[[:alpha:]]+[[:punct:]]?$/) { rec = rec sep $i; sep=" "} print rec}' file
I was there and it was awesome!
```

Comment: This is indeed what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it could be done using Perl:

`perl -ane 'for $f (@F) {print "$f " if $f =~ /^([a-zA-z-\x27]+[?!;:,.]?|[\d.]+)$/} print "\n"' file`

I am using this input text as my test case:

```
Hello,
How are you doing?
I'd like 2.5 cups of piping-hot coffee.
@derik I was there; it was awesome! !! http://url.picture.whatever #hash_tag
```

output:

```
Hello, 
How are you doing? 
I'd like 2.5 cups of piping-hot coffee. 
I was there; it was awesome!
```

Command-line options:

- `-n` loop around every line of the input file, do not automatically print it
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the @F array.  Defaults to splitting on whitespace
- `-e` execute the perl code

The perl code splits each input line into the @F array, then loops over every field $f and decides whether or not to print it.
At the end of each line, print a newline character.

The regular expression `^([a-zA-z-\x27]+[?!;:,.]?|[\d.]+)$` is used on each whitespace-delimited word

- `^` starts with
- `[a-zA-Z-\x27]+` one or more lowercase or capital letters or a dash or a single quote (\x27)
- `[?!;:,.]?` zero or one of the following punctuation:  ?!;:,.
- `(|)` alternately match
- `[\d.]+` one or more numbers or .
- `$` end

Answer (score 0):

`sed -E 's/[[:space:]][^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]][^[:space:]]*//g'` will get rid of any words starting with punctuation. Which will get you half way there.

- `[[:space:]]` is any whitespace character
- `[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]` is any special character
- `[^[:space:]]*` is any number of non whitespace characters

Do it again without a `^` instead of the first `[[:space:]]` to get remove those same words at the start of the line.

Comment: You should replace `a-zA-Z0-9` with `[:alnum:]` to be consistent in use of character classes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the command doesn't do exactly what I need to do. I probably wasn't too clear in the question so here's what I was looking for:

Trim out sub-strings containing special characters (by which I mean any characters that's not a letter) at the beginning or at the middle.
Keep words with punctuation at the end like "Hello, "
Trim out sub-strings with special characters other than punctuation at the end like "HA%"

Thanks again for trying to help!

Comment: Good call. Thanks @EdMorton